# what does "unqualified on right hand side" mean in OOPs (Python)?

Tags: python, oop

I came across "unqualified on right hand side" phrase while reading oops concept in python for usage like self._customer = customer. What that phrase trying to explain? 
Complete statement is

> For example, the command, `self._customer = customer`, assigns the instance variable `self._customer` to the parameter `customer`; note that because `customer` is unqualified on the right-hand side, it refers to the parameter in the local namespace. --[Data Structures and Algorithms in Python](http://multimedia.ucc.ie/Public/training/cycle1/algorithms-in-python.pdf) p. 72

Comment: The statement is obviously wrong, so I would disregard it.

Comment: And the bit which is wrong is that the command assigns the value of the unqualified RHS to the instance variable - not the other way round as the statement suggests

Comment: since I learned a new (useless) term: +1

Comment: @Adam I'm not sure your edit is completely correct. I agree with removing the space from `self. customer` .. but not with replacing it with an underscore. The question makes more sense when the statement is `self.customer = customer` as the qualification is more relevant then (`_customer` and `customer` being different identifiers)

Comment: @kdopen It makes sense in context with the question (note that above, OP has written `self._customer`, and the space was conspicuously where the underscore would be!) I don't mind if it's removed, as it's ultimately irrelevant to the question being asked.

Comment: @kdopen indeed my google-fu has not failed me. Page 71 under "Constructors" http://multimedia.ucc.ie/Public/training/cycle1/algorithms-in-python.pdf

Comment: Yep, when I looked again at the edit I realised you hadn't changed the `_customer` in the initial paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html)

> qualified name
>
> A dotted name showing the “path” from a module’s global scope to a class, function or method defined in that module, as defined in PEP 3155. For top-level functions and classes, the qualified name is the same as the object’s name:
>
> ...
>
> When used to refer to modules, the fully qualified name means the entire dotted path to the module, including any parent packages, e.g. email.mime.text:

Put more simply, qualifying a name in Python means that you explicitly define its scope. Thus `self._customer` is a qualified name (it identifies the instance variable `customer` for the enclosing class) whereas the bare `customer`reference does **not** specify any scope qualifications.

When a name is unqualified, Python applies *Lexical Scoping* rules to try and find the variable, searching (in order)

- Local variables (including function parameters)
- Variables local to any outer functions, if we're dealing with a nested function definition
- Global variables
- Built-in variables

Comment: "Dynamic scoping" is a specific form of variable lookup where you look through the call stack for the most deeply nested function call that has a definition for the variable. Almost nobody does it, because it turns out it's a horrible idea. Python is lexically scoped, and most variable resolution inside functions is static.

Comment: Yeah, sorry - it's always a bit confusing with python :) It's static scoping for symbol binding, but dynamic for value resolution

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to say there, with the "dynamic for value resolution" bit.